# How to enable/disable all keybinds of the same identifier/operator with Python?

Tags: python

[image: example of multiple keybinds of the same identifier]

I found this working code to enable/disable keybinds:

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.move'].active = False
```

But it disables the first keybind it finds instead of all which have `view3d.move` assigned to them.

To disable all of them I thought about running something like:

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
keys = wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.move']

for key in keys:
    key.active = False
```

But got an error `TypeError: 'KeyMapItem' object is not iterable`. I'm still new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keymap_items` is a list that has implemented an iterator over its member's `idname`.  It is possible to have multiple entries in a list with the same value.  Your line

```py
keys = wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.move']
```

returns only the first value.

One way to find all of the keys that have an `idname` of "'view3d.move'" is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this one:

```py
key_list = [key for key in bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items if key.idname == 'view3d.move']
```

The above code says to create a list consisting of all of the keys in the *3D View* keymaps that have an *idname* of view3d.move That will create a list that you can iterate over:

```py
for key in key_list:
    key.active = False
```

Comment: Confirming it works perfectly. Thank you for teaching me :)

Comment: @AlexM you're welcome.